# How can i launch Microsoft Edge in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser, troubleshooting, microsoft-edge

I can't seem to find Microsoft Edge anywhere.

After the most recent update it has disappeared from my Taskbar, my Start Menu got completely wiped and it isn't there either. I tried to search for it using the search function, which is useless as ever and only does searches on the internet or in folders and files, not for installed programs.

As a side effect, any Windows 10 apps I had before the update have disappeared into the void, neither showing as downloaded in the store.

Simple things like calculator are nowhere to be found, and can't be downloaded again, as my computer thinks it's already installed when I finally got into the Windows app store.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to look for it in Start > Apps > M ? It should look like this:

[image: Start]

If you can't find it I would suggest a windows repair / reinstall.

Comment: nothing there under M, (Or C for calculator etc). i really am reluctant to do a reinstall as i only just did one, for a second time.